# Only first frame showed in RTSP Streaming with libvlc

Tags: c++, c, vlc, libvlc

I want to get video of an IP camera and stream it to another IP by libVLC. I write these codes based on examples of libvlc docs. The video streamed successfully and video showed without any problem in destination.But in my display, only first frame was shown. After some search I guessed this problem will be solve by adding `RTP over TCP` option. But after this change my problem didn't solve yet.

I use Microsoft visual C++ and my codes are:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <vlc/vlc.h>
#include <Windows.h>
 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
     libvlc_instance_t * inst;
     libvlc_media_player_t *mp;
     libvlc_media_t *m;


     char *myarg0 = "--sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,scale=Auto,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:duplicate{dst=display,dst=rtp{sdp=rtsp://destinationIP:Port}}";
     char *myarg1="--rtsp-tcp"; 
     char *myargs[2] = {myarg1, myarg0};
     /* Load the VLC engine */
     inst = libvlc_new (2, myargs);

     /* Create a new item */
     char *input="http://user:pass@CameraIP//axis-cgi//mjpg//video.cgi";
     m = libvlc_media_new_location (inst,input ); 

     /* Create a media player playing environement */
     mp = libvlc_media_player_new_from_media (m);

     /* No need to keep the media now */
     libvlc_media_release (m);


     /* play the media_player */
     libvlc_media_player_play (mp);

     Sleep (10000000); /* Let it play a bit */

     /* Stop playing */
     libvlc_media_player_stop (mp);

     /* Free the media_player */
     libvlc_media_player_release (mp);

     libvlc_release (inst);

     return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

here is how i acces a RTSP stream with QT and LIBVLC, this is working well !

```
libvlc_instance_t *_vlcinstance;
libvlc_media_player_t *_mp;
libvlc_media_t *_m;

const char * const vlc_args[] = {
       //   "--verbose=2", //be much more verbose then normal for debugging purpose
    "--network-caching=100",
};

//create a new libvlc instance
_vlcinstance=libvlc_new(sizeof(vlc_args) / sizeof(vlc_args[0]), vlc_args);  //tricky calculation of the char space used
// Create a media player playing environement
_mp = libvlc_media_player_new (_vlcinstance);


/* Create a new LibVLC media descriptor */
_m = libvlc_media_new_location(_vlcinstance, "rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.1.83:554/live0.264");
libvlc_media_player_set_media (_mp, _m);
/* Get our media instance to use our window */
int windid = ui->frame->winId();
libvlc_media_player_set_xwindow (_mp, windid );
/* Play */
libvlc_media_player_play (_mp);
```

where "ui->frame" is the destination object, in my app it's a simple QFrame (but can be everything)

For compile it you need #include  and in the projects settings LIBS += -lvlc

Comment: I found my problem accrued on specific IP cameras. I use another IP camera and streaming was done without any problem